# Read last line of file in bash script when reading file line by line

Tags: bash

I am writing a script to read commands from a file and execute a specific command. I want my script to work for either single input arguments or when an argument is a filename which contains the arguments in question.

My code below works except for one problem, it ignores the last line of the file. So, if the file were as follows.

file.txt

```
file1
file2
```

The script posted below only runs the command for file.txt

```
for currentJob in "$@"
do
    if [[ "$currentJob" != *.* ]]  #single file input arg
    then
        echo $currentJob
        serverJobName="$( tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< "$currentJob" )"  #Change to lowercase
                                                                   #run cURL job
        curl -o "$currentJob"PisaInterfaces.xml http://www.ebi.ac.uk/msd-srv/pisa/cgi-bin/interfaces.pisa?"$serverJobName"
    else  #file with list of pdbs
        echo "Reading "$currentJob
        while read line; do
            echo "-"$line
            serverJobName="$( tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< "$line" )"
            curl -o "$line"PisaInterfaces.xml http://www.ebi.ac.uk/msd-srv/pisa/cgi-bin/interfaces.pisa?"$serverJobName"
        done < "$currentJob"
    fi
done
```

There is, of course, the obvious work around where after the while loop I repeat the steps for inside the loop to complete those commands with the last file, but this is not desirable as any changes I make inside the while loop must be repeated again outside of the while loop. I have searched around online and could not find anyone asking this precise question. I am sure it is out there, but I have not found it.

The output I get is as follows.

```
>testScript.sh file.txt
Reading file.txt
-file1
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  642k    0  642k    0     0   349k      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  492k
```

My bash version is 3.2.48

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It sounds like your input file is missing the newline character after its last line. When `read` encounters this, it sets the variable (`$line` in this case) to the last line, but then returns an end-of-file error so the loop doesn't execute for that last line.  To work around this, you can make the loop execute if `read` succeeds *or* it read anything into `$line`:

```
...
while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    ...
```

EDIT: the `||` in the while condition is what's known as a short-circuit boolean -- it tries the first command (`read line`), and if that succeeds it skips the second (`[[ -n "$line" ]]`) and goes through the loop (basically, as long as the `read` succeeds, it runs just like your original script). If the `read` fails, it checks the second command (`[[ -n "$line" ]]`) -- if `read` read anything into `$line` before hitting the end of file (i.e. if there was an unterminated last line in the file), this'll succeed, so the `while` condition as a whole is considered to have succeeded, and the loop runs one more time.

After that last unterminated line is processed, it'll run the test again. This time, the `read` will fail (it's still at the end of file), and since `read` didn't read anything into `$line` this time the `[[ -n "$line" ]]` test will *also* fail, so the `while` condition as a whole fails and the loop terminates.

EDIT2: The `[[ ]]` is a bash conditional expression -- it's not a regular command, but it can be used in place of one. Its primary purpose is to succeed or fail, based on the condition inside it. In this case, the `-n` test means succeed if the operand (`"$line"`) is NONempty. There's a list of other test conditions [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29), as well as in the man page for the `test` command.

Note that a conditional expression in `[[ ... ]]` is subtly different from a test command `[ ... ]` -- see [BashFAQ #031](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for differences and a list of available tests. And they're both different from an arithmetic expression with `(( ... ))`, and completely different from a subshell with`( ... )`...

Comment: Your suggestion worked, thank you. Based on your answer it seems that at the end of each iteration $line is set to the next value of the next line read and THEN it checks if there are further lines to read with the "read line" argument. The [[ -n "$line" ]] checks if $line is empty? Is this correct. Do you mind explaining exactly what the syntax in the second term means?

Comment: Thank you for the description. I am aware of the structure of the logic and the meaning of the || signs. I know c++ but I am not familiar with the -n command. Does it simply mean "is empty"?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be a missing carriage return in your file.

If you cat your file, you need to see the last line successfully appearing before the promopt.

Otherwise try adding :

```
    echo "Reading "$currentJob
    echo >> $currentJob #add new line
    while read line; do
```

to force the last line of the file.

Comment: This solution worked as well. But wouldn't it possibly lead to problems for input files which did contain the carriage return?

Comment: You can check that the line you work with is not empty

Comment: I worked around this with the following line. if [[ "$line" != *[a-zA-Z0-9]* ]]  This is not checking for an empty line but it does the trick. Do you suggest a better solution?

Comment: I think this `[ "$line" == "" ] && echo "empty"` would do it..

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` with while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
done < <(grep "" file)
```

Using `grep .` instead of `grep ""` will skip the empty lines.

Note:

1. Using `IFS=` keeps any line indentation intact.
2. [You should almost always use the -r option with read.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 0):

I found some code that reads a file including the last line, and works without the [[ ]] command:

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/161645-read-file-using-while-loop-not-reading-last-line.html

```
DONE=false
until $DONE; do
    read s || DONE=true
    # you code
done < FILE
```