# Storing two columns in an array as element -> key using awk

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

Say I have the file `data.log` with the following contents:

```
[12/Mar/2015] /var/lib/file1.txt
[12/Mar/2015] /var/lib/file2.txt
[12/Mar/2015] /var/lib/file3.txt
```

How can I use `awk` and `bash` to store the contents of this file into an array where `[12/Mar/2015]` would be the element and `/var/lib/fileN.txt` its key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bash:

```
# the data
$ cat data.log
[12/Mar/2015] /var/lib/file1.txt
[12/Mar/2015] /var/lib/file2.txt
[12/Mar/2015] /var/lib/file3.txt

# the associative array declaration
$ declare -A map

# read the data from the file into the array
$ while read -r date file; do map[$file]=$date; done < data.log

# iterate through the data
$ for key in "${!map[@]}"; do printf "%s => %s\n" "$key" "${map[$key]}"; done
/var/lib/file3.txt => [12/Mar/2015]
/var/lib/file2.txt => [12/Mar/2015]
/var/lib/file1.txt => [12/Mar/2015]
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine but I seem to be getting only this as output: `/var/lib/file2.txt => [12/Mar/2015]
/var/lib/file1.txt => [12/Mar/2015]` without the last line

Comment: @McJohnson See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485555/read-last-line-of-file-in-bash-script-when-reading-file-line-by-line

Comment: Thank you both. @glenn jackman thank you for your time and answer. Accepted and upped.

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{map[$2]=$1}END{for(key in map){printf "%s => %s\n",key,map[key]}}' infile
/var/lib/file2.txt => [12/Mar/2015]
/var/lib/file3.txt => [12/Mar/2015]
/var/lib/file1.txt => [12/Mar/2015]
```

Or, as a non-one-liner:

```
# For each line, use the second field as key and the first field as value
{
    map[$2] = $1
}

END {
    # Iterate over all keys
    for (key in map) {
        printf "%s => %s\n", key, map[key]
    }
}
```

This goes into a file, for example `script.awk`, and is then called with

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```