# bash to capture specific instance of pattern and exclude others

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to capture and read into `$line` the line or lines in `file` that have only `del` in them (line 2 is an example). Line 3 has `del` in it but it also has `ins` and the `bash` when executed currently captures both. I am not sure how to exclude anything but `del` and only capture those lines. Thank you :).

**file**

```
NM_003924.3:c.765_779dupGGCAGCGGCGGCAGC
NM_003924.3:c.765_779delGGCAGCGGCGGCAGC
NM_003924.3:c.765_779delGGCAGCinsGGCGGCAGC
NM_003924.3:c.765_779insGGCAGCGGCGGCAGC
```

**desired output**

```
NM_003924.3:c.765_779delGGCAGCGGCGGCAGC
```

**bash w/ current output**

```
while read line; do
  if [[ $line =~ del ]] ; then echo $line; fi
done < file

NM_003924.3:c.765_779delGGCAGCGGCGGCAGC
NM_003924.3:c.765_779delGGCAGCinsGGCGGCAGC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
while read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ del && ! $line =~ ins ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < file
```

The revised code is also [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) clean and avoids [BashPitfall #14](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

This solution may fail if the last line in the file does not have a terminating newline.  If that is a concern, see the accepted answer to [Read last line of file in bash script when reading file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15485555/4154375) for a fix.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following(if ok with `awk`).

```
awk '/del/ && !/ins/'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Split it in 2 steps. You do not need a loop:

```
grep "del" file | grep -v "ins"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `sed` solution. It negates the match `del` followed by `ins` and prints everything that has a `del` in it. `-n` to silent every other output.

```
$ sed -n -e '/del.*ins/!{/.*del.*/p}' inputFile
NM_003924.3:c.765_779delGGCAGCGGCGGCAGC
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help and explanations :).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer using PCRE enabled `grep`. This should work with `-P` option in `GNU grep`

```
$ grep -P 'del\.*(?!.*ins)' inputFile
NM_003924.3:c.765_779delGGCAGCGGCGGCAGC
```

Comment: How about records with `ins` first, like `111_ins_222_del`